# Como hago para que me borre los elementos mayor al que seleccione, ya que como la tengo solo me esta borrando el primero

Tags: c++, lista

- Crear una lista doblemente enlazada de números enteros positivos al azar. Insertar por el último nodo.
- Recorrer la lista para mostrar los elementos por pantalla.
- Eliminar todos los nodos que superen un valor dado.

Eso es lo que pide!

Mi problema es que en mi funcion (EliminarNodo) en vez de borrar los elementos de mi lista que sea mayor al numero seleccionado me los borre, pero solo me esta eliminando el primero.

```
int EliminarNodo(NODO **cabeza, int dato)
{
    NODO *actual = *cabeza;
    NODO *ant = NULL;
    NODO *sig = NULL;

    while(actual != NULL)
    {
        if(actual->dato != dato)
        {
            if( actual == *cabeza)
            {
                *cabeza = actual->sig;
                if( actual->sig != NULL)
                    actual->sig->ant = NULL;
            }
            else if( actual->sig == NULL)
            {
                ant = actual->ant;
                actual->ant = NULL;
                ant->sig = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                ant = actual->ant;
                actual->ant = NULL;
                sig = actual->sig;
                actual->sig = NULL;
                ant->sig = sig;
                sig->ant = ant;
            }
            free(actual);
            return 1;
        }
        actual = actual->sig;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner el `free` donde realmente toca y a eliminar el `return 1`?

Comment: `actual->dato != dato` ¿estás seguro?

Comment: Ya pude Solucionarlo, gracias!